# What is any regular expression that matches and capture a multiline string predeced by an undefined number of new lines? [PCRE]

Tags: php, regex, regex-group

I have this multi-line string:

```
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Vivamus
dictum, lorem et fringilla congue, velit libero sagittis eros, id
lobortis nisi risus ac mauris.
```

I would like to use PHP Compatible Regular Expression to "name capture" the second "paragraph" (the 3-line text after the new line).

I tried the following regular expression on [regex101](https://regex101.com/) and it works fine :

```
/\n(\n)+(?<namedGroup>([\w\d]+.*(\n)?)+)/m
```

but when I tried it in PHP using the following code, nothing gets captured :

```
<?php
$text = file_get_contents("paragraphs.txt");

$regular_expression = '/\n(\n)+(?<namedGroup>([\w\d]+.*(\n)?)+)/m';

preg_match($regular_expression, $text, $result);
print_r($result);
?>
```

Comment: If I run your code with the text in the question, I do see a result. https://3v4l.org/5MTA1 You don't need the `/m` flag as there are no anchors, and `[\w\d]+` is the same as `\w+`

Comment: @Thefourthbird I tested your exact code on my Apache server and it doesn't work. I am running PHP 7.4.33. Could it be the reason why it doesn't work ?

Comment: Remove the `\r` chars and it will work: `$text = str_replace("\r", "", $text);`.

Comment: Try running it like this with a match only `$regular_expression = '/\R{2}\K\w.*(?:\R\w.*)*/';` https://3v4l.org/JSU0J

Comment: You can confirm for yourself that it's not about the PHP version on that link; here it is running fine in 7.4: https://3v4l.org/5MTA1#v7.4.33 So most likely there's something about the way you're saving the file that means it's not quite the same - Olivier's comment is hinting at a guess that you have Windows line endings, which aren't matching the \n in the pattern.

Comment: @Olivier it works!

Comment: @IMSoP You are right!

Comment: @Thefourthbird your new regular expression works on windows. can you explain in details (with an answer-post), if you have time, how it works. I've never seen \K and \R in my life

Comment: The `\K` and `\R` are explained within the Notepad++ Online User Manual, See [just before here](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/searching/#assertions) for `\K`. See [here](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/searching/#special-control-escapes) for `\R`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Currently you are using the pattern like this, for which there can be some improvements:

```
$regular_expression = '/\n(\n)+(?<namedGroup>([\w\d]+.*(\n)?)+)/m';
```

You are only matching a newline `\n` and apparently you have `\r\n` in your file. To match those you can use `\R` to match any Unicode newline sequence.

If you want to match only a single value for `(?<namedGroup>` you can actually omit that group at all when making use of `\K` to discard what is matched so far.

Note that:

- `[\w\d]` is the same as `\w` as that also matches digits
- Your pattern has a total of 4 capture groups, where only the named capture group would suffice
- You don't need the `/m` multiline flag, as there are no anchors in the pattern
- The pattern matches only lines that start with a word character `\w`
- Not relevant for the match of interest, but repeating a capture group like this `(\n)+` only captures the value of the last iteration

The updated pattern that you could use for a single match:

```
\R{2,}\K\w.*(?:\R\w.*)*
```

- `\R{2,}` Match 2 or more Unicode newline sequences
- `\K` Forget what is matched so far
- `\w.*` Match a word character and the rest of the line
- `(?:\R\w.*)*` Optionally repeat a Unicode newline sequence, a word character and the rest of the line

Or match only lines that start with a non whitespace character `\S`

```
\R{2,}\K\S.*(?:\R\S.*)*
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AyKdMW/1) | [Php demo](https://3v4l.org/JSU0J)

Comment: OK, now I understand what `\K` is for. I figured what `\R` was for while tinkering my regex.